# How to connect shibboleth idp to mysql instead of LDAP server?

Tags: shibboleth

I'm trying to install shibboleth IDP and SP in windows machine. My aim is to use mysql instead of LDAP. Couldn't find any relevant source. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking how to configure Shibboleth IdP to provide attributes derived from a MySQL source, you would use the `<DataConnector>` element. The following example connects to the database `shibboleth` at `mysqldb.example.com` and defines the attribute `sn`:

```
# In the file attribute-resolver.xml (version 3.3 of Shibboleth Idp)
<AttributeDefinition 
   xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:resolver:ad"
   xsi:type="Simple" id="sn" sourceAttributeID="sn">
  <Dependency ref="mysqlconnector" />
  <AttributeEncoder xsi:type="SAML2String" 
     xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:attribute:encoder"
     name="urn:oid:2.5.4.4" friendlyName="sn" />
</AttributeDefinition>

<DataConnector id="mysqlconnector" xsi:type="RelationalDatabase">
  <ApplicationManagedConnection
     jdbcDriver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     jdbcURL="jdbc:mysql://mysqldb.example.com/shibboleth"
     jdbcUserName="username"
     jdbcPassword="password" />
  <QueryTemplate>
    <![CDATA[
      SELECT sn
      FROM users
      WHERE userid='$resolutionContext.principal'
     ]]>
  </QueryTemplate>
</DataConnector>
```

Note that the above works with Shibboleth Idp version 3.3; for more information, see [the Shibboleth RelationalDatabaseConnector documentation](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/IDP30/RelationalDatabaseConnector).